# Can my pc be hacked through a wireless keyboard / mouse dongle?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, keyboard, mouse, dongle

I have a pc not connected to the internet (to keep my files totally secure). Could the hard drive of my pc be accessed through a usb dongle used wirelessly to connect a mouse and keyboard?

Comment: Keeping it short and simple: no.

Comment: To develop a little on what @Lorenzo said. Most wireless keyboard and mouse sets use a set of radio-frequencies that don't have anything to do with the frequencies wireless uses (essentially they are two separate systems). Now, if someone used a similar keyboard near the USB hub, they could, in theory, write and move your mouse. Accessing your files, no.

Comment: Actually, probably someone COULD set something up to transmit keystrokes to the computer to do nasty things - reboot, erase your hard drive, etc.  But if your computer is not connected to any sort of network then there's no way they'd be able to get any data off the computer.

Comment: You are not saying whether your computer is on when teh USB dongle is 'applied'. Because in that case your problem is not the USB dongle, but the fact that someone has physical access to yuor computer. You would be solving the wrong problem ;-)

Comment: As i know its possible by Mobile partner inject shell code by SMS- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwM2stAu5_Y&feature=player_embedded

Answer (score 1):

A hacker could receive your username and password (or any other keystrokes) from an insecure wireless mouse and keyboard.  However, without a monitor to view the data or an internet connection, there isnt a whole lot they could do.  Typically wireless mice and keyboards have poor range, so they would have to be so close to your machine, they might as well be in the house with you.